Booted to a tty1 screen in Ubuntu KDE after autoremoving ca-certificates
I was having a problem when updating Ubuntu. Certificate verification failed, so I searched on the internet. Then by my own logic and some answers on some forum. I ran the following command:
sudo apt autoremove ca-certificates

Now after restarting my PC I am getting a tty1 screen instead of my normal login screen. I tried pressing the keyboard combination Ctrl+Shift+F7-or-F8 many times. Does anyone have an idea what this is and how to solve it?
I am using Ubuntu with KDE Plasma Desktop full suite. I have uninstalled GNOME.
After trying

sudo apt update && sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop

This I what i am getting:


You've not provided key details, which is what Ubuntu product you're using. You've not said what else you removed (ie. I can look at what effects that would have on my system, but you've not told us what release you're using and thus effects could differ if you're using a different release & install)

A Package ca-cetificates does not exist at all. But if you removed ca-certificates you likely removed your desktop environment. Check your logs /var/log/apt/history.log which packages has been removed and reinstall them. Make sure to read the output apt provides before you confirm to proceed in the future.

Ubuntu 23.04 (along with all flavors) is End-of-Life and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/01/26/ubuntu-23-04-lunar-lobster-reached-end-of-life-on-january-25-2024/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Some of the PPAs in your software sources are not working and should be removed. The first thing you need to do is to restore the default repositories by following the instructions in How do I restore the default repositories?. To help you to restore the default repositories properly this answer has examples of what a standard /etc/apt/sources.list file looks like. Your repositories will have to be replaced by the repositories for unsupported releases because the release that you are using is no longer officially supported;
If you want to re-add the PPAs after you have workable package management, please make a note of every PPA that you removed and add them back one at a time in order to weed out the PPAs that are no longer working. In addition you are using an end of life Ubuntu release and you should upgrade it or reinstall a supported release as soon as possible. Ubuntu 24.04 LTS is scheduled to be released  in five days on April 25. A fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04 will help you more than trying to upgrade from an unsupported release although either one is possible.
In Kubuntu the kubuntu-desktop metapackage has the ca-certificates package as a dependency as do many other desktop environment metapackages in the default Ubuntu repositories.
The tty1 screen that you are stuck at is called a virtual console. You can run commands from a virtual console to repair your system by reinstalling the kubuntu-desktop metapackage.

At the login: prompt type your username and press Enter.

At the Password: prompt type your user password and press Enter.

Reinstall the default desktop environment by running the following command:
sudo apt update && sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop  


Bring up the normal Ubuntu login screen in Ubuntu and then log in:
sudo systemctl start graphical.target




Apt command is not working. I have updated the question with a imgae

Some of the PPAs in your software sources are not working and should be removed.

Thanks it worked. By the way how do I learn all this without losing interest

Fresh install Ubuntu 24.04 LTS as soon as it is released on April 25. I always use the latest LTS version.
